# iOS Swift: Can't read iBeacon manufacturer data (raw data Android equivalent)

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, rxandroidble, ios-bluetooth

I am using this iBeacon BLE device https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/LC01BodyTemperature and trying to read its temperature data.

I've successfully managed to do it in Android Kotlin using [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) by accessing `ScanResult.scanRecord.bytes` and now I'm trying to do the same thing in iOS Swift using [RxBluetoothKit](https://github.com/Polidea/RxBluetoothKit) by reading `ScannedPeripheral.advertisementData.manufacturerData`.

From my understanding of documentation that field should be the Android equivalent of the `bytes` field but in every test I did it always returned `nil`.
I've also tried to access it natively in the `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)` function by accessing `CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey` in `advertisementData` but that also returned `nil`.

The bytes I need to get from the iBeacon's raw data are in position 45 (integer part of temperature) and 46 (fractional part of temperature) but I don't get any byte array whatsoever transmitted in the `advertisementData` of `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)` that has the length suggested by the manual of the device.

Do you have any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's your scan option with the `CBCentralManager`? Your device might appear multiples times in `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)`, the thing, is that's it's might appear piece by piece, sometimes without the name, then with the name, etc. ie, check until the advertisementData be there?

Comment: @Larme I use this options 
`let options = [
    CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "RestoreIdentifierKey",
    CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true
  ] as [String: AnyObject]`
and yes it appears piece by piece but the information I'm looking for it's not present.

Comment: If you use LightBlue.app, does the advertisement appear there?

Comment: @Larme it only shows the Service Data, which does not contain the information I need, it doesn't show the manufacturer data...

Comment: If you post the bytes that Android reads from the advertisement (or the spec of the temp wristband’s advert which is password protected) I can show you how to read this on iOS using CoreLocation APIs.

Answer (score 3):

[You cannot access iBeacon advertisement data using `CoreBluetooth`](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/69112) (which is what RxBluetoothKit uses under the hood).

iOS uses [`CoreLocation` API](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/) for interfacing with iBeacons.

If you want to use iBeacons and advertise some data you have two options:

1. You can encode the temperature data into either major or minor of the iBeacon advertisement and use `CoreLocation` API
2. You can advertise Service Data Type in your advertisement — then you can use `CoreBluetooth` to access that data (because iBeacon advertisement is stripped by iOS in `CoreBluetooth`). From [Bluetooth website](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/):

| data type value | data type name | reference for definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x16 | «Service Data» | Bluetooth Core Specification:Vol. 3, Part C, sections 11.1.10 and 18.10 (v4.0) |
| 0x20 | «Service Data - 32-bit UUID» | Core Specification Supplement, Part A, section 1.11 |
| 0x21 | «Service Data - 128-bit UUID» | Core Specification Supplement, Part A, section 1.11 |

Comment: Doesn't the CoreLocation API just tell me the proximity to the sensor? I can't find the methods that would transmit the data I'm searching for in the documentation. Could you please point me to it?

Comment: I have edited the answer. You cannot get additional data from `CoreLocation` but you can encode data in it. Or you can use a different advertisement data.